# How to deal with multiple extensions overriding the same template file?

Tags: layout, magento-1, extensions, template

I have two extensions which load their own template for the block with name `customer_form_register` in `customer_account_create`

The first extensions overrides the template to **add a new field to the form** and the second extension overrides the template to **add the google recaptcha**.

So there is a conflict and the extension which is loaded last wins and only its template is loaded.

So there is only a new field added to the form but no google recaptcha.

How should I deal with this? Do I have to edit both extensions so that no one of them is trying to load their template and just manually merge both templates and then put it into my design? Or is there a better way?